# Cannot load PNG in C# on Mac OSX running Mono

Tags: c#, macos, mono, bitmap, png

In C#, I'm trying to load a png file on Mac OSX using the latest Mono

```
using System.Drawing;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("test.png");
```

I get the following error

```
Either the image format is unknown or you don't have the required libraries to decode this format [GDI+ status: UnknownImageFormat]
```

It doesn't happen with all png files; just this one.

[image]

Resaving in photo shop doesn't fix it unless I switch to 8bpp.  Is there something I need to install to support this "special" png file?  Works fine on windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried loading this file with mono on my ubuntu and got the following exception:

```
** (mono_load_bitmap:3490): WARNING **: PNG images with 48bpp aren't supported by libgdiplus.
Either the image format is unknown or you don't have the required libraries to decode this format [GDI+ status: UnknownImageFormat]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (System.String filename, Boolean useIcm) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (System.String filename) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Bitmap:.ctor (string)
```

Error

> PNG images with 48bpp aren't supported
>   by libgdiplus

seem to be of the same nature as the one you're having on your mac. Quick google search didn't return any info on how to fix it. My suggestion is try to open it with [Gdk.Pixbuf](http://www.go-mono.org/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aGdk.Pixbuf) class:

```
Gdk.Pixbuf pic = new Gdk.Pixbuf("test.png");
// shows pixbuf in the Gtk.Image widget
Gtk.Image image = new Gtk.Image();      
image.Pixbuf = pic;
```

this call didn't result an error on my ubuntu.

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks Serge. Since my target platforms are Mac and Windows, I decided to just throw a try-catch block around this code and tell artists to change the bit depth on those images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if any MacOS X application can view the image (maybe using libpng)?